# knockout.js custom binding for yes / cancel pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, knockout.js, confirm

I wanted a reusable "yes / cancel" option for elements that when clicked send "review-worthy" POSTs, and didn't use an ugly confirm dialog.  I searched online to little avail, so I created a custom binding using knockout.js -

```
ko.bindingHandlers.confirm = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var $span = $('<span></span>');
    var settings = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

    $span.appendTo($(element));
    $span.text(settings.buttonText);

    $(element).click(function (evt) {

        var $target = $(evt.target);

        //if we're in an anchor tag, prevent questiontext click
        if ($target.hasClass("_confirm") || $target.find("#yes, #cancel").length > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        $span.hide().html(settings.questionText + ' <a class="_confirm" id="yes">yes</a> / <a class="_confirm" id="cancel">cancel</a>').show('fast');
        var submitFunction = settings.submitFunction;

        $(this).find("#yes").on('click', function () {
            //prevent double clicks if event is async
            if ($(this).data('processing')) {
                return;
            }

            $(this).data('processing', true);
            if (typeof (submitFunction) === 'function') {
                //if submitfunction is deferred, double clicks are prevented
                $.when(submitFunction(ko.dataFor(this), evt))
                 .then(function () {
                     $span.hide().html(settings.buttonText).show('fast');
                     $(this).data('processing', false);
                 });

            };
        });

        $(this).find("#cancel").on('click', function () {
            $span.hide().html(settings.buttonText).show('fast');
        });

        return true;
    });
}};
```

to use:

```
<a data-bind="confirm: {  questionText:'Are you sure you want to delete this?', buttonText:'delete', submitFunction:$root.deletePaymentMethod }"></a>
```

So there it is, for anyone that may have been searching. My question is, is there a better way of implementing a "confirm-dialogless" yes/cancel pattern in ko without intermingling so much jquery?

-Thanks kindly!

Comment: Maybe [using templates](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/buf3fryh/) would fit your needs.

Comment: have you looked at creating a knockout component rather than binding handler.

Comment: Origineil's suggestion of utilizing templates worked swimmingly - simple, clean, effective!  Feel free to post an example, I'm a big ko.js fan and interested to see!